# Trying to format Time data to upload to SQL table, however data is returning as NA, despite there being data in the column the NA's are in

Tags: r

I'm trying to read data from an Excel file, perform a series of formatting on the data to align it all into correctly labelled columns which I can then import into a SQL table. Functionality wise and formatting wise, I'm 95% of the way there. The data reads the Excel file, **mostly** formats correctly, then uploads to the SQL table.

The issue I'm having is with column 1 (named time_of_call), which is time data, after I've renamed the dataframe columns (combined_data), I try to format the columns as time (using as.POSIXct), the data returns as NA.

The reason why I'm formatting the data as.POSIXct, is due to R reading the data in column 1 as 45126.3463666654754754 -> number of days since 1900. I can't use this data in the SQL table, I need it to be in time format, but for some reason it won't work.

It's also worth noting too that the initial formatting in column 4 is effected the same way as I described above, however the as.POSIXct works fine with the column 4 data (named Duration)

```
library(cmooreFunctions)
basic_setup()
library("readxl")
library("dplyr")

con_qv <- dbConnect(drv = odbc(), 'ufpukecom01_QV')

all_sheets <- excel_sheets('.../Call report_.xlsx')
all_sheets

list_all <- lapply(all_sheets, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(
    read_excel(".../Call report_.xlsx", sheet = x))
}) 

names(list_all) <- all_sheets

Sheet1 <- list_all$"Sheet1"
Sheet2 <- list_all$"Sheet2"
Sheet3 <- list_all$"Sheet3"
Sheet4 <- list_all$"Sheet4"
Sheet5 <- list_all$"Sheet5"
Sheet26 <- list_all$"Sheet26"

Sheet1 <- subset(Sheet1, select = c(2,4,9,14,19,25))%>%
    rename('Time Of Call' = "...2", 'Call Type' = "...4", 'Extension' = "...9", 'Duration' = "...14", 'Number' = "...19", 'User Name' = "...25")

Sheet26 <- subset(Sheet26, select = -c(2, 5, 6, 9))

combined_data <- rbind(Sheet2,
                       Sheet3,
                       Sheet4,
                       Sheet5)

combined_data <- subset(combined_data, select = -c(4,7))

combined_data <- rbind(combined_data, Sheet1, Sheet26)

# Formatting the combined_data
combined_data <- combined_data[complete.cases(combined_data), ]
combined_data <- combined_data[combined_data[, 6] != 'User Name', ]
combined_data <- combined_data[combined_data[, 2] == 'Out', ]
combined_data[, 5] <- as.character(combined_data[, 5])
combined_data[, 5] <- ifelse(substr(combined_data[, 5], 1, 1) != "0", 
                             paste0("0", combined_data[, 5]), 
                             combined_data[, 5])
combined_data[, 5] <- ifelse(substr(combined_data[, 5], 1, 2) == "00", 
                             paste0("0", substr(combined_data[, 5], 3, nchar(combined_data[, 5]))), 
                             combined_data[, 5])
combined_data <- rename(combined_data,
                        time_of_call = `Time Of Call`, 
                        call_type = `Call Type`, 
                        extension = Extension, 
                        duration = Duration, 
                        number = Number, 
                        username = `User Name`)
combined_data$time_of_call <- as.POSIXct(combined_data$time_of_call, format = "%H:%M:%S")
combined_data$duration <- as.POSIXct(combined_data$duration, format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: The [openxlsx](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=openxlsx) package has a function [`convertToDate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.5.2/topics/convertToDate) which handles Excel's decimal representation of time. It also uses the proper origin dates for Excel. Take a look at that, perhaps.